# Amazon Cognito - Is there any way to bypass a Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Is there any way to bypass a Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger when creating a cognito user?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The lambda is optional. You don't have to set one up.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad yes, I understand that, but I have a large user pool in place that uses the trigger and I need to create a user (for testing purposes) that will not pass my pre sign up logic, therefore I want to create a user bypassing the trigger

Comment: Then I suggest modifying your lambda code to ignore certain username. You can't bypass the trigger completely. Ending the function when it reads a certain username is the best you can do.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad yeah, unfortunately, I came to that same conclusion.